# Installing MediaWiki on Linux

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, gcc, lamp, mediawiki

I'm am new to Linux and generally new to setting up a web dev environment. I need help with the basics right now. I'm trying to install a LAMP stack that I can then install MediaWiki on. Here's what I'm attempting to do right, let me know if I'm way off track here.

1. Installing Apache

   1. Downloaded Source
   2. Attempted to Build/Install
   3. No gcc found
   4. Downloaded gcc
   5. Attempted to Install gcc (No luck)
2. Install phpMyAdmin
3. Install MediaWiki

Am I on the right track at least or am I spinning my wheels?

Linux distro: CentOs

Comment: Do you need to build from source or are you okay using a binary package?  Which distribution are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I on the right track at least or am I spinning my wheels?

Uhm, both.

If you use **source code** then you will need a compiler.
If you use pre-build **packages** (e.g. .rpm or .deb) then you do not need a compiler.

Regardless of method used, having a working compiler is a good thing and I would split your tasks into two parts:

1. Get a working compiler, which will be useful for a lot of tasks. Without a previous compiler you will have to install this via a pre-build package.
2. Decide on home build or pre-build programs.

For maintainability reasons you really want to use packages.

Just which packages and how differs per OS. E.g. redhat/CentOS is different from Ubuntu. Both are quite different from Slackware, etc etc. You did not specify which distribution you used. Please add that to the original post.

Also, you do not need phpMyAdmin?  You do need a database to store your wiki contents in. That can be mysql or postgress. Management tools for those might come in handy, but each unneeded software package installed is an extra program which you have to maintain.

Comment: I thought I needed phpMyAdmin. I thought the purpose of it was to easily install php & mysql onto Apache.

Comment: Need: No.  ---- Make things easier: Maybe.  ---- If you are not used to doing this than a helpful tool might be very nice, so go ahead an install it. Jut make sure you keep it up to date (as really with all installed software).

Comment: Okay. Another question with the Apache install. Do I just download the NetWare Binary from the mirror site?

Comment: It shouldn't difficult to unzip the binary right? I'm running the unzip command and it keeps saying it can't find the file and its sitting right in the current directory

Comment: Disregard last question.

Comment: This page might be useful:   http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Administration/s1-apache-inshttpd-CA.html

Answer (score 2):

You're on a valid path, but you seem to be taking the harder of the paths available to you. As @heavyd implied, it's much easier to install binary packages that come with your distribution for things like Apache and phpMyAdmin. For RHEL / CentOS / Fedora, use yum; for Debian and Debian-like flavors, use apt. If you're using a distribution that expects you to build from source, then continue as you have begun but realize that it will be a long and arduous journey.